# AWS EventBridge - Customize s3 event pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, events, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have a s3 bucket with EventBridge events enabled and I have the following bucket structure.

```
s3://bucket/db/table/LOAD00001.csv
```

I need to create an event pattern that will identify all new files that contains "LOAD" in the filename.

My event pattern looks like:

```
  {
      "source": ["aws.s3"],
      "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
      "detail": {
        "bucket": {
          "name": [{
            "suffix": "-landing"
          }]
        },
        "object": {
          "key": ["*LOAD*"]
        }
      }
    }
```

I have tried some combinations using prefix and suffix but no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

Event [content filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html) does not support wildcard pattern matching.

If prefix or suffix matching does not work, consider overfetching and using the event target to screen out unwanted events.

```json
"key": [{"prefix": "LOAD"}]
```